# failed to open stream: Permission denied in set to 777 but not running

Tags: php, html, csv

Hi I try to export an html to csv with php, base on this question [Converting HTML Table to a CSV automatically using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498632/converting-html-table-to-a-csv-automatically-using-php), everything going fine until I realize that my code is not running because I set the permission to 777, If I revert this back to 755, it returns me this error `failed to open stream: Permission denied in`, is there something I'm missing out here?

Comment: What's the permission on the folder?

Comment: oh you mean folder that contains the .php file? it's still on 755, I just set 777 to the .php file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can't just give full access to my folder, I found this question and kinda solve my problem [Error failed to open stream permission denied when trying to create page in public_html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634508/error-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-when-trying-to-create-page-in-publ)